# Extracting Office 2010 from Windows 7 ISO image

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, iso-image

I have ISO image of Windows 7 that contains Office 2010 in it. I wonder if I can extract only Office 2010 files and install it on different computer.

That ISO id provided by corporate IT Department. Currently I am running Windows 8.1 trial version. I want install Office 2012 on that Windows 8.1 Computer.

Comment: Office 2012 or 2010 ?

Comment: If the ISO is provided by your IT department, then you should ask them. Corporate IT questions are off topic as Superuser is for "personal and home computer networking".

Comment: @Kiwy - Office 2012 is not even a Windows application. I am going to guess since the author wants to extract the Office 2010 from the image they actually mean they want to install Office 2010 on their Windows 8.1 trial installation.  The simplest solutio of course is to install the Windows 7 installation with Office 2010 already installed and upgrade that to Windows 8.0 then install the Windows 8.1 update.  Of course this requires either a Windows 8.0 or Windows 8.1 license to acomplish.

Comment: @Ramhound I 'm not really uptodate with microsoft product as I don't use them that much :D

Comment: @Kiwy - All the more reason to do research on an unfamilar topic.

Comment: It is Office 2010. Actually, I could ask IT guys there to share Office 2010 installation file. I believe we have corporate license (or how do you call it). Anyway thank you for your replays.

Answer (score 2):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) will happily take an ISO and extract it into a file and folder structure.

At this point, you'll need to have a hunt around for a folder containing the installation files. If you're lucky, it'll be a folder at the top level which you can then install as you wish.

Comment: I actually could open ISO file, but it seems it will be hard to find installation files. Those files somehow hidden.